# my r2_score is negative

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

My work at college is to estimate the value of some points. So,  I need to predict 8 points based in another 8 points. When i run the algorithm, the output values are not even close to the input values. Can anyone help me? My algorithm is that, so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from keras.layers import Dense, Input
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array(pd.read_csv('dimensoes.csv'), dtype=np.float64)

data_x = data[:, 0:8]
data_y = data[:, 8:16]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data_x, data_y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

regressor = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(110,),
                         activation='relu',
                         batch_size=150,
                         learning_rate_init=0.001)
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train)
predict = regressor.predict(x_test)

r2_score(a, previsao)
r2_score(previsores, dimensoes)
```

Comment: Why don't you give the actual data points to make it feasible for the community to help you? And I am curious why you have multiple y "data [:, 8:16]?"?

Comment: You can not do machine learning on eight data points. Any results will not be useful. Even estimating the mean with a sample size of eight will not be stable.

Answer (score 1):

Negative $R^2$ is definitely possible. It means your model is no better than a constant. In other words, your model is utterly rubbish, and worse than do nothing (e.g. just predict everything by a simple mean).

Your model needs more data points than 8. Please ask yourself what you're trying to accomplish here.